# Not able to return value from promise in Nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have written the following code in Nodejs which is saving data in MongoDB:

```
function insertDoc(db,data){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      callback=db.collection('AnalysisCollection').insertOne(data).then(function(response,obj){
        console.log("Inserted record"); 
           resolve(obj);
        //console.log(obj); 
          //  response.on('end',function(){
          //    resolve(obj);
          //  });  
        //return resolve(obj);
    }).then(() => { return obj }
    ).catch(function(error){
        throw new Error(error);
    });
    })
  }
```

I am calling the above function from the main function like this:

```
async function cosmosDBConnect(nluResultJSON){

    try{
        //console.log("Inserting to cosmos DB");
        console.log(nluResultJSON);        
        var url = config.cosmos_endpoint;
        var result="";

        var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(nluResultJSON));

        MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client) {
          assert.equal(null, err);
          var db = client.db('NLUAnalysisDB');          
         // insertDoc(db, data, function() { 
          result=insertDoc(db, data, function() { 
            console.log(result);                      
          client.close();
          //return data._id;
          });          
          });

          
    }
    catch (e) {        
        console.log(e);
      }
}

module.exports = { cosmosDBConnect };
```

But in cosmosDBConnect, I am getting 'undefined' for the result, though in insertDoc I am getting the output for'obj' with _id for the inserted record.

Please help me to return this _id to cosmosDBConnect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are use callbacks inside of `async` function, which creates internal scopes. So your `return` aplies to them instead of whole function. You should use [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)-based methods inside of `async` function using `await` (without callbacks) or wrap whole function into own [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) otherwise.

Example:

```js
function cosmosDBConnect(nluResultJSON) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var url = config.cosmos_endpoint;
        var result = '';

        var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(nluResultJSON));

        MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client) {
            if (err) return reject(err);
            assert.equal(null, err);
            var db = client.db('NLUAnalysisDB');
            insertDoc(db, data).then(obj => {
                console.log(obj);                      
                client.close();
                return resolve(data._id);
            });           
        });
    });
}
```

Also you need to understand that your `insertDoc` return [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and *do not* accept callback you tried to pass.

Ref: [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Comment: it is still not printing result. Please help.

Comment: Make sure your `insertDoc` function accept callback you trying to use in `cosmosDBConnect`

Comment: my insertDoc function is exactly how I have written in my question, do you think that also needs to be changed?

Comment: @SormitaChakraborty I clarified my answer

Answer (score -2):

```
result = insertDoc(db, data).then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
}).catch(err => console.error(err));
```